# Ajax data not passing to controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem where the data in the ajax isn't passing the sessionStorage item. I have tried using JSON.stringify and added contentType: 'application/json' but still it's not passing. Can this be done using POST method? Also, I have debugged and returned those sessionStorages, hence the problem isn't because the sessionStorge doesn't contain data.

Here my function:

```
    function functionA() {
        $.ajax({
            url: URLToApi,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            data: {
                access_token: sessionStorage.getItem('pageToken'),
                message: $('#comment').val(),
                id: sessionStorage.getItem('pageId')
            },
            success: function () {
                $('#success').text('It has been added!"');
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem has been found. The issue was the sessionStorage, hence I've passed it directly to the URL and now it working as follows:

```
   function functionA() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:#####/api?id=' + sessionStorage.getItem('pageId') + '&access_token=' + sessionStorage.getItem('pageToken') + '&message=' + $('#comment').val(),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#success').text('It has been added!"');
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check below things in Controller's action that**

1. there should be a matching action in controller
2. name of parameter should be same as you are passing in data in ajax
3. Method type should be same the ajax POST of the action in controller.

```js
 function AddPayment(id, amount) {
        var type = $("#paymenttype").val();
        var note = $("#note").val();
        var payingamount = $("#amount").val();
        $('#addPayment').preloader();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Fixed/AddPayment",
            data: {
                id: id,
                amount: payingamount,
                type: type,
                note: note
            },
            success: function (data) {
                
            }
        });

    }
```

[image]

Here is the working code from my side.
Check with this, and for the header part you need to get it from the Request in action

Comment: They are all checked, the problem still persists

Comment: @MexicoBoy I have updated my answer please look into it give me feedback

Comment: This doesn't work in my case because `type` & `note` aren't added by the user, I'm getting them from the API

Comment: @MexicoBoy type and note is used in my case, not in yours so ignore it. just look, that what i have done and not in your case.

Comment: Yes that's what I have done, but when I'll check the values they are undefined because obviously I'm getting the values session storages